# Why converting interface{} to uint32 doesn't work even when the actual value is in the range of uint32

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a YAML string and store it as `uint32` using [gopkg.in/yaml.v2](https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2).

When I try to convert a value `foo` as follows, I get an error message that says: `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is int, not uint32`. I can't understand the reason why I see the error message, because the value `foo` is actually `3` and it's in the range of `uint32`.

```
var myYaml = `
foo: 3
`

type SampleYaml struct {
        Foo interface{}
}

func main() {
        var sampleYaml SampleYaml
        var uint32Val uint32

        yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(myYaml), &sampleYaml)

        uint32Val = sampleYaml.Foo.(uint32)
        fmt.Println(uint32Val)
}
```

Here's the [actual code](https://play.golang.org/p/LzfsofiMatq) that I'm struggling with.

Comment: YAML uses a native integer data type, not `uint32`

Comment: It doesn't matter if it fits in `uint32`, because you're not doing a type conversion, you're doing a type assertion. You can assert it to the true underlying type, then coerce it to `uint32` if it fits.

Comment: I concur with the answer by @hbejgel but the real question is: is it possible that your real YAML documents may contain non-integer values at that "foo" key? The reason I'm asking is that the way to go may be implementing a custom type which implements the `encoding.TextUnmarshaler` interface, accepts the raw value's data in the form of `[]byte` and is then free to interpret it in whatever the way it wants and produce the value of the concrete type(s) you want.

Comment: Look [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/#TextUnmarshaler) and [here](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/3e6d767784b037b90a14701b6c9f0643f05db963/decode.go#L394). Oh, and if the answer to my question is "no" then just declare your `Foo` field as `uint32` rather than `interface{}`.

Comment: @kostix Yes, my real YAML data may contain values except `uint32`. It can be a boolean, it can be a string, etc. `encoding.TextUnmarshaler` sounds promising. Thanks!

Comment: @SaOh, oh, by the way I meant creating a custom type to unmarshal the `Foo` field, not the enclosing field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the spec:

> If T from v.(T) is not an interface type then such assertion checks if dynamic type of v is identical to T

When you do type assertion the dynamic type of v has to be identical to T, according to your error message the dynamic type is `int` and you're trying to assert it to `uint32` that won't work since they are not identical.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
uint32Val = uint32(sampleYaml.Foo.(int))
```

You first use type assertion to get an `int` from your `interface{}` and then you use type coercion to have your `uint32`

Comment: One minor nitpick in that in a real production code it might worth complicating the approach a bit by 1) using two-argument type assertion and returning an error if it fails, and 2) checking whether the range of the obtained `int`-typed value is within the range of `uint32` before type-converting it, and returning an error if it's not. In the demonstrated approach, a panic and a silent reinterpretation of data are both possible.

Comment: Agreed, this example was just to demonstrate how to do it in the simplest way possible. (with no intention of guarding against invalid data)

Comment: Thanks @hbejgel ! I have another question then. Why does Go compiler think that the dynamic type of `v` as `int` instead of `uint32`? Is there an priority order or something to determine the type of `v`?

Comment: @SaOh, 1) I don't think that's Go compiler; I'd fathom it's the implementation of that YAML codec package; 2) I'd speculate `int` is picked as the "default sane/safe choice". Let's suppose the author(s) decided to implement more "strict" typing. That would mean looking at the raw value and seeing it does not start with `-`, so it has to be an `uint`. Then what size to pick? Why 32? There are `uint8` and `uint16` and `uint64` types as well. So what do we do then? Count the digits and pick the "narrowest" suitable type? So `32` would be unmarshaled to `uint8` and `65537` to `uint32` etc.

Comment: @SaOh, Do you find it convenient? ;-) Also consider that should the raw value start with `-`, it would have been classified as belonging to one of the four signed integer types. Now, to "decapsulate" a value of a concrete type at runtime you'd have to deal with a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches) with 8 branches. That's not convenient, too. OTOH, `int` is a "jack-of-all-trades" here: it may not be the "best" (in whatever sense) type but it makes many things way more straightforward.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for the clarification! It got much more clearer now :)